# Uncaught ReferenceError: (XXXXXXX) is not defined

Tags: html

I think I found the shortest javascript code that could trigger the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: (XXXXXXX) is not defined"

The Javascript code I used is:

```
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
    const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
    canvas.width = innerWidth
    canvas.height = innerHeight

    class Player {
      constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.radius = radius
        this.color = color
      }
      draw() {
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, (false))
        c.fillStyle = this.color
        c.fill()
      }
    }


    class Projectile {
      constructor(x, y, radius, color, velocity) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.radius = radius
        this.color = color
        this.velocity = velocity
      }

      draw() {
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, (false))
        c.fillStyle = this.color
        c.fill()
      }

    }


    const x = canvas.width / 2
    const y = canvas.height / 2
    const player = new Player(x, y, 30, 'blue')
    player.draw()


    addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      const projectile = new Projectile(event.clientX, event.clientY, 5, 'red', null)
    })


    projectile.draw()
```

The HTML code I used is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <body>

      <canvas></canvas>
    </body>

    </html>
```

I think my website is throwing the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: projectile is not defined because there is a problem somewhere along in this part of the javascript code here...

```
addEventListener('click', (event) => {const projectile = new Projectile (event.clientX, event.clientY, 5, 'red', null)})


    projectile.draw()
```

I don't understand. The `const` projectile is clearly there on the third code snippet but why my website failed to see it. Is my website blind? (LOL!)

I don't understand why. I'm dazed and confused.

I was just following this tutorial on how to make games. The time stamp where I slumped is in minute 23:00 out of 1 hour, 56 mins and 49 seconds of this video...

[image: wtf]

Thank you all!

The enlarged version is here:

[image]

Edit: The correct Javascript code so that you won't have the "Uncaught ReferenceError: (XXXXXXX) is not defined" error is:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d') 
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

class Player {
    constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.radius = radius
        this.color = color
    }
    draw() {
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2,  (false))
        c.fillStyle = this.color
        c.fill()    
    }
}


class Projectile {
    constructor(x, y, radius, color, velocity){
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.radius = radius
        this.color = color
        this.velocity = velocity
    }

    draw() {
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2,  (false))
        c.fillStyle = this.color
        c.fill()    
    }

}


const x = canvas.width / 2
const y = canvas.height / 2
const player = new Player (x, y, 30, 'blue')
player.draw()




addEventListener('click', (event) => 
    {
        const projectile = new Projectile (event.clientX, event.clientY, 5, 'red', null)
        projectile.draw()
    }
)
```

The `const` projectile must be inside the `addEventListener` function so that it won't throw an error....:-)

Comment: `projectile` exists inside the function, not outside it.

Comment: @Quentin Ah I see...but how the code snippet in guy's video worked for him but not mine? I'm confused what's my difference between me and him because I just copied his code.....

Comment: I'm not going to watch a video to find out what you mis-transcribed.

Comment: @Quentin I edited the question and now encircled the part of code where I slumped, the picture that I attached. Thank you for your help, comrade!

Comment: `projectile.draw()` does not appear in the code you circled.

Comment: Re edit: I refer you to my initial comment about being **inside** the function.

Comment: @Quentin I put an enlarged picture in the post and it seems the error is the same...Thank you!

Comment: @Quentin I edited the question and now encircled the part of code where I slumped, the second picture that I attached. Thank you for your help, comrade!

Comment: Yes, I saw, hence why I said: Re edit: I refer you to my initial comment about being inside the function

Comment: @Quentin Holy smokes....I now understood what you meant. It now worked. Thanks for your time, comrade!